# Probability of error in a communication channel.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This channel takes as input a Random Variable $V$ and gives as output a Random Variable $X=V+N$ where $N$ stands for a $Standard$ $Normal$ R.V (expected value of $0$ and variance of $1$).

> In order to transmit $0$ the input must be $V=-1$
>
> In order to transmit $1$ the input must be $V=1$

If $X<0$ the receiver decides that $0$ was sent, else if $X>0$ the receiver decides that $1$ was sent.

$V$ and $N$ are independent R.V.

What is the probability of error happening in the transmission if $0$ was transmitted?

I guess I have to find the $P(X>0\mid V=-1)$ where $X=V+N$ . I tried analyzing that but it came to a dead end (with Bayes theorem).I am sure I have to use the fact that $N$ follows the typical normal distribution but I find no connection.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what role $V$ being a random variable plays here. You don't specify a distribution for it, and you don't talk about it like a random variable (e.g. "in order to transmit"). It seems to me that the problem would be more clearly stated if $V$ were a deterministic message to be transmitted and only $N$ were random.

Comment: @joriki $V$ displays a voltage signal and $N$ is the "noise" distribution. There are no more information about $V$.

Comment: Then why are you framing it as a random variable?

Comment: @joriki it is defined as a random variable in the exercise (we only know that it might equal to $-1$ or $1$ ).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) (in particular the section on providing context). When you post questions that come from exercises, it makes sense to state that to provide context.

Comment: @joriki it's not an exercise from a book. My professor gives us weekly sets of exercises, so even if they are taken from a book I wouldn't know which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $X\raise{0.05ex}:=V+N$, so:
$$\begin{align} \mathsf P(X>0\mid V=-1) ~=&~ \mathsf P(V+N>0\mid V=-1)
\\[1ex] =&~ \mathsf P(N>1\mid V=-1)
\end{align}$$

Now, since the noise ($N$) is *independent* of the state of the signal ($V$) then: ...

Comment: Yes, I just shouldn't try to solve this with the Bayes theorem. Thanks!